# Is Gaussian process model impacted by order of variable index?

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, gaussian-process

I'm learning about Gaussian Process through this video by Richard Turner (University of Cambridge, link below). In the video, it was explained that GP is a generalization of multivariate Gaussian distribution and a plot of variable indices ($X_i$) vs response ($Y$) was considered (attached below). From the explanation, it seems like the error bars of variable ($X_i$), thus its probable values, depend on the prior variables i.e. $X_k$ for $k<i$.

1. Does this mean depending on how I arrange the variables, I would get different distributions for my prediction?
2. If so, would Gaussian Process be most appropriate for time-series data?

Link to video ~ 18:00 min :  https://youtu.be/92-98SYOdlY?t=1005

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Gaussian Processes assume an underlying continuum. That being time, space, acidity, or simply the values a regularisation parameter. The error bars in this example are indeed associated with the placement of the know points but that is completely expected; the further away we are from a know point, the more uncertain we are about the estimated value.
2. I would not say "*most appropriate for time-series data*" but I would note that time-series modelling through Gaussian Processes is a well-accepted application of GPs. Roberts et al. (2012) [Gaussian processes for time-series modelling](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/full/10.1098/rsta.2011.0550) is a pretty authoritative reference to start off if you want to read on this further.